# Convert lastname, firstname middleinitial to different columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I currently have a column named PersonFullName. It has data in it like this:

```
PERSONFULLNAME  
Doe, John A  
Doe, Jane M  
Doe, Eric
```

I am wanting to get the data in this format:

```
LastName  -  FirstName  -  MI  
DOE    -     John    -     A  
DOE    -     Jane    -     M  
Doe    -     Eric
```

Below shows up fine, but if I add a middle initial, the middle initial lands in the First name column.

```
declare @last as varchar(20)
declare @first as varchar(20)
declare @mid as varchar(20)

declare @name varchar(100)
select @name = 'Leake, Angela'

set @last = substring(@name, 1,charindex(', ',@name)-1)
set @first = LTRIM(substring(@name, charindex(' ',@name),len(@name)-charindex(' ',@name)+1))
set @mid = RIGHT(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@name))-1)
If (@mid=@first) SET @mid=''

select @last as 'Last Name', @first as 'First Name',@mid as 'Middle Name'

Select PERSONFULLNAME FROM Kronos
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, as well as attempts you have made to solve the problem.

Comment: Would this answer help? [How to split string into columns for a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150593/how-to-split-string-into-columns-for-a-view)

Comment: Is your data really this simple, or do you need to account for additional spaces, suffixes, periods, hyphens, apostrophes, etc., not to mention multiple cultures? Any significantly large list of free-text names will have exceptions to virtually any logic you can come up with.

Comment: I am working to join 2 tables together, but 1 table is formatted as the PERSONFULLNAME   -which is standardized inputs, and the other table is formatted as LASTNAME FIRSTNAME MI    -which is not standardized inputs.

Comment: @AlbertVincent I would be careful when joining on name. There are a few Joseph A. Smiths out there.

Comment: @TimLehner I know, and that is what has me terrified about this project. My job here is basically linking Multiple different databases together, and creating software to do automatic data analysis on the results. I have thought about having the free form db to realign the way they input data, but the manager doesn't want his team to have to do "MORE WORK..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes okomikeruko that worked. I am still learning SQL, so I didn't know about that CTE.

The following did exactly what I needed...

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  PERSONFULLNAME,
            LEN(PERSONFULLNAME)-LEN(REPLACE(PERSONFULLNAME,' ','')) N
    FROM Kronos
)
SELECT  PERSONFULLNAME,
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(PERSONFULLNAME,' ','.'),N) 'First Name',
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(PERSONFULLNAME,' ','.'),N+1) 'Last Name',
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(PERSONFULLNAME,' ','.'),N-1) 'MI'
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Is this the Kronos time keeping system?

Comment: Ok, I've played in that DB before and remember the name being split in the [PERSON] table. Not sure what your environment looks like but I was just curious.

Comment: I only have a linked server with execute credentials to an SP that they created for me. Due to HR/Finance SOX standards that is all that I am allowed to see. Also, the data was created in it's current format around a year ago. There are multiple automated programs that are built around the current formatting. So with the new system that I now have a linked server to, I am having to create my own formatting in my db to accommodate.

Comment: Ah I see. Always harder when they won't give you the keys to the kingdom.

Comment: I'm working on it lol. I currently have ALMOST EVERY system in our site linked to each other in 1 form or another. Our inventory system is all that is left lol